# Convex conjugate of the sum of smallest elements

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

I recently came across this problem to find the conjugate function of the sum of $r$ smallest elements in a vector

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=n-r+1}^{n}x_{[i]} \text{ for } x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

where $x_{[i]}$ is the $i^{th}$ largest element in vector $x$.

My first approach is as follows:

We consider the following function in two cases:
$$
y^Tx - f(x)
$$
If $y$ has component $y_i \ge 1$ for some $i$, we can construct $x$ such that $x_i$ is very positive ($x_i = t$ where $t \gg 0$), and other components of $x$ are all zeros, then
$$
y^Tx - f(x) = y_it \rightarrow \infty
$$
If $y$ has component $y_i < 1$ for some $i$, we can construct $x$ such that $x_i$ is very negative ($x_i = -t$ where $t \gg 0$), and other components of $x$ are all zeros, then
$$
y^Tx - f(x) = -y_it + t = (1 - y_i)t \rightarrow \infty
$$Therefore,
$$
f^*(y) = \infty
$$
I wonder if this is the right solution. Any idea is highly appreciated.
Thank you all!

Comment: The second conjugate is the convex envelope, I e. the largest convex function below. In this case, this is zero (since your function is non-neg and zero along the axes). Hence, the conjugate is the pre-conjugate of the zero function which is the indicator of {0}.